# Does a continuous multiplication operation on a complete normed algebra imply the Banach algebra norm condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I know that the Banach norm condition
$$
\|ab\|≤\|a\|\|b\|
$$
implies continuous multiplication but is the converse true? How would one go about proving this or constructing a counter-example?

Comment: By the uniform boundedness principle the continuity of multiplication implies $\|ab\|\le C\|a\|\,\|b\|$ for a positive constant $C.$ Then the new norm $C\|\cdot\|$ is submultiplcative.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Your point being that $C\|\cdot\|$ is equivalent as a norm to $\|\cdot\|$, so modulo norm-equivalence the converse is true, right?

Comment: That's right. Sometimes this may be unpleasent if we have $\|e\|=1,$ and we loose that property as $C\|e\|=C>1.$ But it can be repaired by taking Another norm $$\|a\|_m=\sup \{\|ax\|\,:\|x\|\le 1\}$$